# How to parse data using PHP into MySQL tables from XML files that have formats which are not universal and can change?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, parsing, search

Problem:

I am to build a web-based tool in PHP to help users access information scattered across a collection of XML files that I plan to store data from into tables in MySQL. A lot of examples I see online seem to be based on importing data from a bunch of XML files that all use the same formatting. I do not have that luxury.

How would I be able to parse through XML files that have the following factors?

- There are multiple categories of XML files in this collection, each having separate formats and types of information that differentiate each category. Ideally, I would create a separate table for each category. However...
- Additional new categories of XML files could be added to this collection without my knowledge ahead of time.
- Any existing category could have its format restructured and/or the types of information within could be increased or decreased, also without my knowledge ahead of time.
- Even among the same category of XML files, there can be older files that have an outdated formatting version.

Expected Results:

Using an example where the collection of XML is about a group of people, if you search for "brown eyes", you get search results listing pages for everyone listed with brown eyes. One of the pages is "Robert". If you click this result, you'll go to a page where all the information from Robert's XML file is displayed (readable formatting to be handled later).

Comment: sounds like the perfect time to use a NoSQL database. MongoDB and Redis being the most popular choices currently

Comment: When these unforeseen changes to the collection occur, is there a requirement that the tool can handle the new collection without any code changes? Or is it expected that you (or someone) will need to modify the tool accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could only create a self-learning parser, which adds new columns to the table whenever it finds new properties in the `XML`. basically there are two options available: either build up a data model, which at some point in time matches all the records - or stuff the mess into a noSQL database, which does not necessarily make the mess any better. "one size fits all" (stuffing unstructured data into a structured database) is not an option.

Comment: I think we're going to go with a parser that first checks that tables for the XML category exists and then that each field exists as a column (and adds/creates accordingly). Talking with those who manage our XMLs, 99.99% of changes are purely addition instead of subtraction or rearrangement of fields. We feel those edge cases are easy to mitigate after a quick brainstorm. Thanks for the brain food!

Comment: @Vicros that parser might need occasional adjustments, whenever processing a new batch of files. eg. detecting the type/version of input document, adding mappings for changed field names, etc. developing with a backup of the actual database suggested. it's all about finding the lowest common denominator, in terms of a data structure. having tables which have the information about file-format versions and column mappings might be required.